# CUDA linking Error undefined reference

Tags: c, compilation, cuda, nvidia

I'm new to CUDA programming hence running into issues with compiling/ linking files. I'm trying to compile `.c` and `.cu` files. 
Here are the files: 
`p3.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  

extern void load_scheduler(int k, int j);
int blocks, threads;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        blocks = atoi(argv[1]);
        threads = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    else
        exit(1);

    load_scheduler(blocks, threads);

}
```

And `scheduler.cu` file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void sched_func()
{   
    int j = 6*5*threadIdx.x;
    printf("%d\n",j);
}

void load_scheduler(int b, int n)
{
    sched_func<<< b,n >>>();
}
```

I compile these two files using `nvcc -c scheduler.cu p3.c` and it seems fine 
However, when I try to link these two files using `nvcc -o cuda_proj scheduler.o p3.o`, I get an error:

```
p3.o: In function `main':
p3.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `load_scheduler'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I may not be using the right steps to get this working, so if there's any other way I should try out, suggestions are welcome. I am also new to making Makefiles so want to stick to using nvcc commands on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Just added : `extern "c"` before load_scheduler definition. NVCC could not recognize the function definition as it belonged to `.cu` file, therefore the error.

```
extern "C"
void load_scheduler(int b, int n)
{
    sched_func<<< b,n >>>();
}
```